# mplayer couldn't find audio filter 'resample'

Tags: debian, video, mplayer, video-encoding, multimedia

I've been converting a bunch of mp4 files to dvd format with movie-to-dvd (from videotrans).

Most of the converting went fine, but some files can't be converted and fail with the following message:

```
... many lines omitted. If some information is missing, please ask
Couldn't find audio filter 'resample'
[libaf] Couldn't create or open audio filter 'resample'
Error at audio filter chain pre-init!

... more lines omitted
```

Under the hood videotrans just uses mplayer. The mplayer command that causes this error is this:

```
mplayer -slave -identify -noframedrop -nojoystick -nolirc -vo \
yuv4mpeg:file=/tmp/.movie-to-dvd.12234.yuv -channels 2 -ao \
pcm:waveheader:file=/tmp/.movie-to-dvd.12234.wav -af \
resample=46034:0:2,volnorm -osdlevel 0 -zoom -vf scale=720:576,harddup \
-- movie.mp4
```

(The line breaks and corresponding line breaks were added by me)

I guess I'm just missing some shared library and installing the right package (I'm on debian) would fix it. But I can't figure out which package is missing.

Operating system: Debian jessie Linux/GNU i386 (i686)
mplayer version: 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1